# Numbered equation with inline text

Tags: amsmath

I am quite new to LaTeX so please excuse me for my ignorance. I can not figure out how to write a numbered equation with inline text. Can someone please tell me why this does not work? I use `\usepackage{amsmath}`.

```
\begin{equation}
\sqrt{\lambda}=n \pi \qquad \text{for $n=1,2,3$ \ldots}
\end{equation}
```

The expression works fine without the text but I really need it included because my expression is a series.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE. Works fine here. Did you remember `\usepackage{amsmath}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\sqrt{\lambda}=n \pi \qquad \text{for $n=1,2,3$ \ldots}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

produces:

[image: numbered equation with text]

This isn't what is usually meant by 'inline' but I'm guessing you have something different in mind. You need `amsmath` to define `\text` in maths mode. Otherwise, you can do something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\sqrt{\lambda}=n \pi \qquad \mathrm{for}\ n=1,2,3\ \ldots
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

which does not require `amsmath`.

Comment: why use `\mathrm` for `\ldots`?  punctuation is always "roman" (upright) in math.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks. Why? Just because the original example did. I'll edit in a minute. I don't typeset enough maths to recognise when somebody has done something differently...